# What is the "general" type for an array of enum?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a method that would like to take as parameter an **array of Custom `Enum` types**.

Something that would look **like this**:

```
public void DoSomething(WhatDoIPutHere[] parameters)
```

I would like to pass to this method either a `Enum1[]` or a `Enum2[]` where `Enum1` and `Enum2` are 2 `Enum` types.

**What do I need to use instead of `WhatDoIPutHere` ?**

I would have expected to define the signature of DoSomething as `Enum[]` as somehow `Enum` is the base class for Enum types (right?) :

```
public void DoSomething(Enum[] parameters)
```

but it gives a :

> cannot convert from 'xxx.Enum1[]' to 'System.Enum[]'

I also tried defining it as `object[]` but I get the same kind of compiler error..

I know this is totally smelly code, and if I could I would definitely get rid of it ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Value type arrays aren't covariant. You sort of *want* to write:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T[] parameters) where T : struct, System.Enum
```

... but that's not allowed either (type parameters can't be constrained to be enums or delegates).

Options:

- Allow *any* array:

  ```
  public void DoSomething(Array parameters)
  ```
- Allow any array of value types:

  ```
  public void DoSomething<T>(T[] parameters)
  ```
- Use [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) to write the first form, via IL-rewriting hack.

Comment: wow, thanks, that was a fast and thorough answer! I'll go for the first option then... I can't really change the method signature too much (i.e. adding generic type) so option 2 is out... and option 3 .. I would probably need to study that, but another time :)